# Unintentional impersonation in WCF service

Tags: wcf, impersonation

(Note: I finally resolved this myself and the impersonation turned out not to be the main problem; however, if anyone knows why the impersonation takes place, please let me know.)

We have a WCF service that is being called from a Silverlight application (they are hosted by the same web application). Calling the service is surprisingly slow compared to how much time the operation itself takes. The WCF trace log makes it look like more than two seconds are spent on impersonation (see the fifth line):

```
[15:32:3.193] From: Processing message 1.
[15:32:3.193] Activity boundary.
[15:32:3.193] Received a message over a channel.
[15:32:3.194] ServiceChannel information.
[15:32:5.539] Security Impersonation succeeded at the server.
[15:32:5.540] To: Execute 'MyNamespace.GetFloorplan'.
[15:32:5.540] Activity boundary.
[15:32:6.302] From: Execute 'MyNamespace.GetFloorplan'.
[15:32:6.302] Activity boundary.
[15:32:6.305] Sent a message over a channel.
[15:32:6.306] Activity boundary.
```

This baffles me, because I thought that impersonation was something you needed to explicitly enable in the configuration (or trigger from the code). I was just brought in on this project as a consultant, so I don't have a full overview of the entire source code yet, but the text "impersonate" or "impersonation" does not exist anywhere in the source code. Adding to the confusion, `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` from inside the service returns an unauthenticated identity with no name, and `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` returns `IIS APPPOOL\MyCustomAppPool`, so the impersonation doesn't really seem to have accomplished anything.

We use forms authentication and ASP.NET compatibility mode. When I disable the latter (which I'm not sure I can do permanently, because there might be functionality that depends on it that I don't know about yet), `Security Impersonation succeeded at the server` disappears from the log, but the time difference between `Received a message over a channel.` and `To: Execute 'MyNamespace.GetFloorplan'.` is still almost two seconds. Adding `[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.NotAllowed)]` to the operation does not help.

Does anyone understand what is going on here? (My goal is to get rid of the impersonation or whatever it is that takes up those two extra seconds.)

---

We have the following attributes on the service class (I know they should ideally be on the interface, but I haven't found out yet whether there is a reason they were placed on the service in the first place):

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[SilverlightFaultBehavior]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
                                 AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

Here is our service configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                             multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="SilverlightServiceBinding">
        <binaryMessageEncoding />
        <httpTransport />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="MyNamespace.FloorplanService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="SilverlightServiceBinding" 
                contract="MyNamespace.FloorplanService" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And our client configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_FloorplanService" 
               maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <security mode="None" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="../Floorplan/FloorplanService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_FloorplanService"
              contract="FloorplanServiceProxy.FloorplanService" 
              name="BasicHttpBinding_FloorplanService" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the impersonation message was a red herring (which I should have understood because it disappeared when disabling ASP.NET compatibility mode, while the request still took almost as much time). However, the WCF trace log did point me in the right direction: *something* very time consuming was obviously happening in WCF prior to the operation actually being invoked. Eventually, we found that the web application contained a user authentication/authorization class that, due to an improperly configured dependency injection container, was being invoked several times per request, causing many unnecessary database requests.

Lesson learned (in case others stumble across the same problem): depending on your configuration, WCF may call authentication and authorization mechanisms before your code executes, and these may take up a non-negligible amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your IIS Authisettings for your web site.

If you have several Authentication types enabled, and it is trying one of the other authenication types first.

Comment: Interesting suggestion; however, only Forms Authentication and Anonymous Authentication are enabled for the web application (and we need the Forms Authentication in order to verify that the logged-on user may access the requested resource).